# loadbitmap return null outside fragment

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, bitmap

i am using LoadBitmap() in fragment and it returning null outside the fragment.
As in my application i have 4 tab fragment and from one of the 4 fragment i have return code of loadbitmap, it is used to load image from gallery while checking its density and all. the image gets attach properly but when after sending any image i click on other tab then the application gets crash and through exception of null pointer exception in loadbitmap function

```
public void loadBitmap(Message message, ImageView imageView) {
    Bitmap bm;
    try {
        bm = xmppConnectionService.getFileBackend().getThumbnail(message,
                (int) (metrics.density * 288), true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        bm = null;
    }
    if (bm != null) {
        cancelPotentialWork(message, imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    } else {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(message, imageView)) {
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xff333333);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(
                    getResources(), null, task);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            try {
                task.execute(message);
            } catch (final RejectedExecutionException ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this line i am getting error
    bm = xmppConnectionService.getFileBackend().getThumbnail(message,
                (int) (metrics.density * 288), true);

Please help me to resolve out from fragment issue how will i manage bitmap in fragment

Comment: what is xmppConnectionService?

Comment: line 5 check if metrics.density is not null.  like if(metrics.density==null){ } also check xmmp service is initiated .

Comment: Also remove parentheses around metrics.density*288. You want to convert density to int first then multiply with 288

Comment: thanks for your solution. i have tried this but it is not working still it get crash

Comment: Hello all, can anyone help me i am facing many issues regarding fragment like i have image sending code in fragment and when i send any image to my chat application then it just show sending status but in actual image is sent then i just go back from my existing fragment then it update it status to sent. please help me out from fragment related issue and also i am facing the same above problem yet. it is not resolved by above solution